# How to adjust image size on viewdidload ios

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview, uiimage

I have to setup logos on table view cells. But the size of the logos is bigger than needed. So I need to reduce all logos proportionally lets say divide the height and width by 1.5 when the view loads. I have achieved this but when the tableview reloads, the logos get smaller. This happens every time the tableview reloads. How can I achieve the desired results?

Answer (score 0):

If you divide the height and width of the image view by 1.5 every time the cell is loaded then it will get smaller and smaller. Just set the height and width to a constant value.

Comment: I cannot do that. all logos are not of the same shape. some are square and some are rectangular. logo images load dynamically depending on the company name.

Comment: Then you can subclass the UITableViewCell, and override awakeFromNib: to make the adjustment only once.

Answer (score 0):

How are you scaling the images? If you do not share details and/or code, it is difficult to understand the issue and offering help.

Anyway, can't you just set the `contentMode` on the containing UIImageView so images are automatically scaled down to fit the available space?